# EC2 Data Pricing, Gigabits or Gigabytes?

Tags: amazon-ec2

This is most likely a stupid question but regarding [Amazon EC2 Pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) are the "data out" prices listed in $/Gigabyte or $/Gigabit. I'm fairly sure it's Gigabyte but just wanted to double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect Amazon to use standard notation. So, a `GB` represents a [`Gigabyte` or `1,000,000,000 bytes`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units#Gigabyte_per_second).

If they wanted to say `Gigabit`, they would have used `Gb` instead which is [`1,000,000,000 bits`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units#Gigabit_per_second).

Best place to ask this question is [Amazon EC2 Developer Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=30)

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units